# Proper way to store json in database

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Does json usually have enclosing quotation marks when stored in a database field?

Which of the following would be correct for the `json` column?

```
`json`
'{"Color": "Red"}'
 {"Color": "Red"}
```

My assumption would be the second, but just wanted to make sure that's correct. And if so, why?

Comment: I don't think there's some general 'correct' answer for that. Personally I'd go with the second as well

Comment: Are you asking about whether apostrophes should appear *in the data*?  If they do, then the column values are not JSON.  One does not normally include string delimiters within the data, as it alters the meaning of the data.  The answer is different, however, if you're asking about the syntax of an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: json is just text. you store it like you would any OTHER text: be mindful of [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

If you use earlier version and store it as text, store it without the enclosing quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to store the data as you suggest, it would be better to store the data in a table named `json` with field `color` then insert two records, each containing the value 'red'.

It's more work now, because it involves deconstructing and reconstructing the JSON, but it saves work later if you need to serve the data in some format other than JSON, then you won't need to reformat all of the data in your database.